# when i write @foreach($products as $product) it's destroy all html which is inside it and no thing appear

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

When I write `@foreach($products as $product)` it's destroying all html which is inside it and nothing appears.

[image]

**Web Route code**

```php
Route::get('/product/tag/{tag}', [IndexController::class, 'TagWiseProduct']);
```

**IndexController**

```php
public function TagWiseProduct($tag){
    $products = Product::where('status',1)
    ->where('product_tags_en',$tag)
    ->where('product_tags_ar',$tag)
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->paginate(3);
    $categories = Category::orderBy('category_name_en','ASC')->get();
    
    return view('frontend.tags.tags_view',compact('products','categories'));
}
```

**tags_view.blade page**

```html
    <div class="search-result-container ">
              <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content category-list">
                <div class="tab-pane active " id="grid-container">
                  <div class="category-product">
                    <div class="row">
    
    
    
    
    @foreach($products as $product)
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow fadeInUp">
                        <div class="products">
                          <div class="product">
                            <div class="product-image">
                              <div class="image"> <a href="{{ url('product/details/'.$product->id.'/'.$product->product_slug_en ) }}"><img  src="{{ asset($product->product_thambnail) }}" alt=""></a> </div>
                              <!-- /.image -->
                              
                              @php
            $amount = $product->selling_price - $product->discount_price;
            $discount = ($amount/$product->selling_price) * 100;
            @endphp     
              
              <div>
                @if ($product->discount_price == NULL)
                <div class="tag new"><span>new</span></div>
                @else
                <div class="tag hot"><span>{{ round($discount) }}%</span></div>
                @endif
              </div>
                            <!-- /.product-image -->
                            
                            <div class="product-info text-left">
              <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ url('product/details/'.$product->id.'/'.$product->product_slug_en ) }}">
                @if(session()->get('language') == 'arabic') {{ $product->product_name_ar }} @else {{ $product->product_name_en }} @endif</a></h3>
              <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
              <div class="description"></div>
                            @if ($product->discount_price == NULL)
    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> ${{ $product->selling_price }} </span>   </div>
    
    @else
    
    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> ${{ $product->discount_price }} </span> <span class="price-before-discount">$ {{ $product->selling_price }}</span> </div>
    @endif
                              <!-- /.product-price --> 
                              
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.product-info -->
                            <div class="cart clearfix animate-effect">
                              <div class="action">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                  <li class="add-cart-button btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary cart-btn" type="button">Add to cart</button>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="lnk wishlist"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Wishlist"> <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
                                  <li class="lnk"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Compare"> <i class="fa fa-signal"></i> </a> </li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.action --> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.cart --> 
                          </div>
                          <!-- /.product --> 
                          
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.products --> 
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.item -->
    
    
      @endforeach
            
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row --> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.category-product --> 
                  
                </div>
                <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                
    
                
                <div class="tab-pane "  id="list-container">
                  <div class="category-product">
    
     @foreach($products as $product)                
                    <div class="category-product-inner wow fadeInUp">
                      <div class="products">
                        <div class="product-list product">
                          <div class="row product-list-row">
                            <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                              <div class="product-image">
                                <div class="image"> <img src="{{ asset($product->product_thambnail) }}" alt=""> </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.product-image --> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col -->
                            <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                              <div class="product-info">
                              <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ url('product/details/'.$product->id.'/'.$product->product_slug_en ) }}">
                  @if(session()->get('language') == 'arabic') {{ $product->product_name_ar }} @else {{ $product->product_name_en }} @endif</a></h3>
                <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
                                @if ($product->discount_price == NULL)
                <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> ${{ $product->selling_price }} </span>  </div>
                @else
    <div class="product-price"> <span class="price"> ${{ $product->discount_price }} </span> <span class="price-before-discount">$ {{ $product->selling_price }}</span> </div>
                @endif
                                <!-- /.product-price -->
                                <div class="description m-t-10">              @if(session()->get('language') == 'arabic') {{ $product->short_descp_ar }} @else {{ $product->short_descp_en }} @endif</div>
    </div>
                                <div class="cart clearfix animate-effect">
                                  <div class="action">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                      <li class="add-cart-button btn-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary icon" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary cart-btn" type="button">Add to cart</button>
                                      </li>
                                      <li class="lnk wishlist"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Wishlist"> <i class="icon fa fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
                                      <li class="lnk"> <a class="add-to-cart" href="detail.html" title="Compare"> <i class="fa fa-signal"></i> </a> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  <!-- /.action --> 
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.cart --> 
                                
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.product-info --> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col --> 
                          </div>
    
    
                           @php
            $amount = $product->selling_price - $product->discount_price;
            $discount = ($amount/$product->selling_price) * 100;
            @endphp  
                          <!-- /.product-list-row -->
                                  <div>
                @if ($product->discount_price == NULL)
                <div class="tag new"><span>new</span></div>
                @else
                <div class="tag hot"><span>{{ round($discount) }}%</span></div>
                @endif
              </div>
    
    
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.product-list --> 
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.products --> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.category-product-inner -->
                    
                   @endforeach
                    
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.category-product --> 
                </div>
                <!-- /.tab-pane #list-container --> 
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-content -->
              <div class="clearfix filters-container">
                <div class="text-right">
                  <div class="pagination-container">
                    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                      <li class="prev"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                      <li class="next"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.list-inline --> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.pagination-container --> </div>
                <!-- /.text-right --> 
                
              </div>
              <!-- /.filters-container --> 
              
            </div>
            <!-- /.search-result-container --> 
            
          </div>
          <!-- /.col --> 
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: You have 15 opening but 17 closing divs

Comment: Your `html` is invalid for a start, you have mismatched opening and closing elements. Aside from that are you certain your `$products` variable has a value?

Comment: first things first re-assess your html tags if they are properly implemented, 
second debug the value of $products if it has content or value.

Comment: @Peppermintology every thing is ok but doesn't working the same error

Comment: @ALAAELDIN Does `$products` have a value?

Comment: @Peppermintology yes it has value